# How to make group order

Tags: asp.net, linq

I want to make group order this table but I can not group a column.

[[this is my first gridview]](https://drive.google.com/open?id=10SX_W6FdRtdEVjCJLDGmtfN-7sHZLaPm)

This is my gridview at above. I want to transform that is like below.

[[I want to transform as this]](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QnM2r1CxShf1OQrlEGhdxfAcZS0K6thS/view)

but I can not do. I use this code:

```
var info = (from c in db.myTable
            group c by c.name into groups
            select new
                   {
                       id = groups.Key,
                       ogrencininAdi = groups.Select(n => n.ogrencininAdi).FirstOrDefault(),
                       ogrencininSoyadi = groups.Select(n => n.ogrencininSoyadi).FirstOrDefault(),
                       ogrenciNo = groups.Select(n => n.ogrenciNo).FirstOrDefault(),
                       dersinAdi = groups.Select(n => n.dersinAdi).FirstOrDefault(),
                       yokZamani = groups.Select(n => n.yokZamani).FirstOrDefault(),
                       kacinciDers = groups.Select(n => n.kacinciDers).ToList(),
                 }).ToList();

gridViewabsentStudent.DataSource = info;
gridViewabsentStudent.DataBind();
```

but I have a problem on this line:

```
Order = groups.Select(n => n.Order).ToList()
```

`Order = groups.Select(n => n.Order).FirstOrDefault()` is unsuccessful.

I want to a solution about this problem. I hope that I described my problem

[this is my final screen.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1h6vdm96oY73qAoAKTL7PjvZMwpJGospQ/view?usp=sharing)

in that column was stored:

```
"System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Nullable`1[System.Int32]]"
```

I want to see second photo in that column.

Comment: I am not sure what you are tying to achieve... Can you explan better?  Are you trying to order by c.Name then create that kacinciDers  column as "1,2"?

Comment: show in kacinciDers column that group by 1,2 etc. may be that can be over 1,2,3 or 1,2,3,4,5 etc. I want to escape that repeat of kacinciDers seperate 1 or 2 rows. . I want to take all of them a row as 1,2,3,4 etc.

Comment: I do not want to change any data from table. table will stay as same but I want to take them from table as second photo by linq query

Comment: "unsuccessful" doesn't say much. What did you get? What do you *want* to get? (Please edit that into your question as text, not image)

Comment: I changed my problem, added third photo. Unfortunately i can not write by text format that database screen. .I am sad

Comment: Now I am trying to making spaces by spacebar key but, editor is clearing my spaces. so that looks verybad. so I am adding photo again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the last image you posted, it seems all you need is a string representation for your kacinciDers property.

changing to below in your `select` should work, if I understood the problem 
 correctly.

```
var g = (from c in db.myTable
     group c by c.name into groups
     select groups)
    .AsEnumerable(); // first lets change this to Enumerable

var model = g.Select(groups => new
     {
         id = groups.Key,
         ogrencininAdi = groups.Select(n => n.ogrencininAdi).FirstOrDefault(),
         ogrencininSoyadi = groups.Select(n => n.ogrencininSoyadi).FirstOrDefault(),
         ogrenciNo = groups.Select(n => n.ogrenciNo).FirstOrDefault(),
         dersinAdi = groups.Select(n => n.dersinAdi).FirstOrDefault(),
         yokZamani = groups.Select(n => n.yokZamani).FirstOrDefault(),
         kacinciDers = string.Join(", ", groups.Select(n => n.kacinciDers.ToString()).ToList()),
     }).ToList();

gridViewabsentStudent.DataSource = model;
```

Post a comment if that didn't work, and I will be happy to help.

Comment: I am sad but I can not resolve  in "groups.Select" "groups. OK. I understood. that is "grupla"

Comment: Did you mean you figured it or do you need help?

Comment: When I changed as kacinciDers = string.Join(", ", grupla.Select(n => n.kacinciDers).ToList()),
 I took this message "{"LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String Join[Nullable`1](System.String, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Nullable`1[System.Int32]])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."}" It is normal but, how can I change that? that column is int32

Comment: That is because of the type mismatch. I updated the answer to change kaciniDers toString(). That should work. Let me know.

Comment: I am checking at the moment

Comment: I am very sad but this is an error {"LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String Join(System.String, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.String])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."}

Comment: I can not use in linq queries "ToString() methot." Yes, you understood what mean. I can read code but, I have a another problem.

Comment: Hang on. I didn't realize it was linq to entities. We can still solve it. hold on...

Comment: Can you try that and see if it works. I don't have an EF project set up, so I can't verify.

Comment: I am trying at the moment. Give me some minutes to transform to my project

Comment: extraordinary problem. Error CS0841 Cannot use local variable 'g' before it is declared. Another error is: Use of unassigned local variable 'g'

Comment: Did you change the ‘var info’  to ‘var g’?

Comment: yes of course, I can not writee too code in here. but I will share a photo about it

Comment: <a href="https://drive.google.com/open?id=1RQVBK6BOiM9sbIGD6bx0M8cBTi3VyzVG"> this is a screenshot </a>

Comment: My bad. You need to change ‘select g’ to ‘select groups’ in line 65

Comment: how can not see I. I am trying again now

Comment: Super Super Super. It is okey. Thank you

Comment: Can I ask a question? about another? @NoSaidTheCompiler

Comment: why did not .ToString work without .AsEnumerable()?

Comment: When you are using Linq to Entity, it will try to convert your linq statement to sql equivalents. Since sql doesnt have string.join, u were getting the error. When we do AsEnumerable, it no longer tries to create a sql query and therefore it works. Glad I could help! Please up vote and accept the answer if it solved your problem :)

Comment: how can i order  " kacinciDers = string.Join(", ", groups.Select(n => n.kacinciDers.ToString()).ToList())" this part? i can not write orderby methot on this sentence

Comment: i solved as                         kacinciDers = string.Join(", ", groups.Select(n => n.kacinciDers.ToString()).ToList().OrderByDescending(n=>n).Reverse()),